# What are the simplicies?

Tags: category-theory

Let $X$ be a bisimplicial set: that means that $X$ is a simplicial
object in simplicial sets.  Let $\Delta^n$ be the collection of simplicial sets
given by 
$$
\Delta^n(m):=\Delta(m,n),
$$
so we could say $\Delta^n:=\Delta(\underline{\phantom m}, n)$. How would I simply describe 
$$
|X|=\int^{n\in\Delta}\Delta^n\otimes X_n
$$
as a simplicial set?  In particular, what is the set of simplices $|X|_n$ for each $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that in $\Delta^n\otimes X_n$ the tensor product is the ordinary product, as it is on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SimpSet).

This functor is a colimit, and as a colimit, I think you'll struggle to say anything interesting about its simplices except by just taking the construction of the colimit as a coequalizer, and bashing it out.

So let's do that.
Taking the definition gives you that $i$-simplices of $|X|$ are the quotient of the set of all pairs $(a :i\to n, b_n)$ of $i$-simplices of $\Delta^n\times X_n$ by the smallest equivalence relation generated by $(a,f^*b_m)\sim (f\circ a,b_m)$ where $b_m\in X_m(i)$ and $f:n\to m$ is a morphism in $\Delta$.

Note then that we always have $(a,b_n) \sim (\mathrm{id}_i,a^*b_n)$. Thus the $i$ simplices will be $X_i(i)$ for all $i$. I assume therefore that $|X|$ should be the composite of $X$ with the diagonal functor $D:\Delta^{\text{op}}\to \Delta^{\text{op}}\times \Delta^{\text{op}}$.

To prove this, we could do the following
$$
\newcommand\of[1]{\left({#1}\right)}
\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}
\newcommand\sSet{\mathbf{sSet}}
\begin{align}
\sSet(|X|,S)
&=
\sSet\of{
\int^{n\in\Delta}
\Delta^n\times X_n
,S
}
\\
&=
\int_{n\in\Delta}
\sSet(\Delta^n\times X_n,S)
\\
&=
\int_{n\in\Delta}
\int_{m\in\Delta}
\Set\of{
X_n(m)\times \Delta(m,n), S(m)
}
\\
&=
\int_{n\in\Delta}
\int_{m\in\Delta}
\Set\of{
\Delta(m,n), 
\Set\of{
X_n(m),
S(m)
}
}
\\
&=
\int_{n\in\Delta}
\Set\of{
X_n(n),
S(n)
}
\\
&=
\sSet(X\circ D,S).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: what is $f*b_m$ mean?

Comment: I use $f^*$ to denote the application of a contravariant functor to $f$. In this case, $f^* = X_f(i)$.